# How to speed up single query in an loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I try to create an stock web app by php.

There is an stock list (about 2,000 stocks), each stock with an specified ID.

Then I set an loop to fetch the latest price from other site by function file_get_contents

Here is the pseudo-code,

```
<?php
$stock_arr=Array();
//get stock ID list from my database then fill the $stock_arr array.
for($i=0;$i<count(stock_arr);$i++){

    $cur_id=stock_arr[$i];
    $url="http://example.com/r=".$cur_id;
    $json=file_get_contens($url);
    updateprice($json,$cur_id);

}
```

I had set an simple timer,and found each query spends about 0.3 seconds.

For 2,000 stocks,it`s about 6~8 mins. And I dont think it is acceptable.

Since the query and update of each stock were not related. I thought there might be better algorithm.

Could someone give me some hint to speed up the process?Thanks.

Comment: Try curl multi, it can have multiple parallel  connections.

Comment: From the look of things you are getting an external resource? You have to take into consideration that they might not have the fastest response times.

Comment: First of all, I would take off that `count` in the for loop and store it in a variable.

Comment: 2000 requests to a php server in under a minute... I would block you in an instance seeing it looks like you are performing a DOS, which is basically what you are doing. Instead try it in parts. Request 100 or 200 records per call. It will not only speed up the process immensely from your side, but the other side will be way happier too.

Comment: Hi Matt,Thanks.I am now trying the curl multi request way.Indeed,only about 100 records were feedback!The latters returns empty.I think it might be kicked by the server. Could you kindly explain more about what I should do?Should I add a usleep() every 100 queries or other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "curl multi example php", you can find functions like one here
http://kahthong.com/2012/04/php-parallel-curl-request-curlmultiexec-and-curlmultigetcontent